# Convergence for improper integral $\int_0^\infty x^re^{-x} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm trying to find for which values $r$ the following improper integral converges.
$$\int_0^\infty x^re^{-x}\, dx$$
What I have so far is that $x^r < e^{\frac{1}{2}x}$ for $x \geq a$, which splits the integral into
$$\int_0^a x^re^{-x} \,dx + \int_a^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}x} \, dx$$
We know the latter interval converges, but I don't know what to do with the first one. (For reference, graphing the functions reveals the answer to be $x > -1$.)

Edit: I would like a proof without the gamma function. Preferably one that uses the comparison test to compare limits.

Comment: This is actually one of the more interesting integrals in mathematics. try plugging in $ r = 1, 2, 3, 4...$ etc. What do you notice?

Comment: Hint:$$\int\limits_0^{\infty}\mathrm dz\, x^n e^{-x}=n!=\Gamma(n+1)$$

Comment: Did anybody even read the OP's question or do they just want to use the post to mention the gamma function?

Comment: @AniruddhVenkatesan I know it equals $n!$ for natural numbers, but for this question I'm mainly interested in for which real values of $r$ the interval converges.

Comment: @DionelJaime As I recall, the original question didn't mention not using the gamma function, with this being added afterwards.

Comment: @DionelJaime Yes I saw what he posted, I felt as though the gamma function would help to prove, just now saw the OP's edit

Comment: I imagine the edit was done in response to people mentioning the gamma function in the comments, but not responding to his actual question about convergence.

Comment: @DionelJaime yes, in response to comments. WolframAlpha also used gamma but there has to be a way to prove that it only converges for $r>-1$ without gamma?

Comment: It's defined for $$\{z\in \Bbb C | \Re(z) > 0\}$$

Comment: Can Gamma function be used for limit comparison test. If we know that the gamma function converges, then we can show that your integral converges

Comment: I guess $\Re(r)\gt -1$

Comment: I think my posted answer addresses the question. I don't see that the accepted answer does that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^r e^{-x}}{x^{-2}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{r+2}}{e^x} = 0 $$

since the exponential function tends to infinity faster than any polynomial.  Hence, by the limit comparison test the integral over $[1, \infty)$ converges since $\int_1^\infty x^{-2}\, dx = 1$.

See if you can finish by finding the condition on $r$ such that the integral over $[0,1]$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \text{For small enough }a>0, \\[8pt]
& x^r > x^r e^{-x} > 0.9 x^r \text{ when } 0<x<a.
\end{align}
Therefore $\displaystyle \int_0^a x^r e^{-x} \, dx$ converges for precisely those values of $r$ for which $\displaystyle\int_0^a x^r\,dx$ converges.